# Is there a method of determining where the = operator from class X is called within a preexisting project using overloaded operators through code?

Tags: c++, logging, operator-overloading

Someone posed a question to me, they have a preexisting project, there is a variable that isnt behaving correctly and is causing memory issues, how can I help.

So I wanted to test a theory of mine where I created a basic templated class with a overloaded = operator to monitor any modification to the object.

```
template<class T>
class Tracker : public T
{
public:
    Tracker() {};
    T& operator=(const T& other);
};

template<class T>
inline T& Tracker<T>::operator=(const T& other)
{
    std::cout << "Tracked Object Changed: " << std::endl;
    T::operator=(other);
    return *this;
}
```

So on my question, is there a way to determine where the overloaded = operator is called from (class/function/line number) to be able to log it to a text document for review later.

Comment: well in C++23, you could use [stacktrace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/basic_stacktrace/current)... (C++20’s `source_location` is unusable for an operator, sadly). On anything below, `boost` should be usable, or compiler-specific extensions themselves.

Comment: A debugger can be used at runtime.